# Force Full Path For Method

Tags: vb.net, function, module, intellisense

I'm not sure whether that's the best title but what I'm trying to do is set certain Subs and Functions to be only accessible from other functions by qualifying the exact location.

For example, I have a module called modShared.
In this module there is a function called LogForm which returns a Form.

In other areas of my code I have functions where the name begins with Log so I want the LogForm function to only be accessible and only appear on Intellisense when I type in modShared.LogForm and not just LogForm.

Is this possible because it would help me immensely?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.Net - Variables in Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913950/vb-net-variables-in-modules)

Comment: The last paragraph and code block is what you need

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't quite "get" what they were saying on that link, but the post below worked for me.

Comment: Essentially the same but, as usual, Vincent's answer is superior anyway :)

Comment: @AFriend : Aww, now you're flattering me ;). (5 hours later, heh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your module to a static class and apply the [**`Shared` modifier**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared) to every method and you should be good to go.

```
Public NotInheritable Class modShared
    Private Sub New() 'Prevent initialization.
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function LogForm() As Form
        'Do stuff...
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.  That works perfectly, but it means I'll have to go through all my Subs, Functions, Variables, etc. and set them as shared. I thought it may have been a quick keyword to add in to the module declaration or something. Either way, it gives me what I want. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @SteMoore : Glad I could help! Two tips for the future that you can use to speed up the process of modifying the methods: **1)** Copy the `Shared` word, then move the selection to where you want to insert it and press `CTRL + V` on your keyboard to paste (repeat for every method). || **2)** Press `CTRL + F` to open Visual Studio's `Find and Replace` dialog. Make sure you search only in the current document, then search for `Public` and replace all with `Public Shared`.

Comment: @SteMoore : If you're prepared to do something a little more advanced when replacing you can enable Regular Expressions in the `Find and Replace` dialog, then search for `(Private|Protected|Friend|Public)` and replace with `\1 Shared`.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is placing your modules inside a [Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/namespaces)

```
Namespace UtilityMethods
    Module modShared

        Public sub LogForm()
            'Code Here
        End sub

    End Module
End Namespace
```

And you could use this code by either calling:

```
UtilityMethods.LogForm
```

or

```
Namespace UtilityMethods

    Public Class MyClass

        Public sub ClassMethod

            LogForm()

        end sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: If only you'd replied earlier... I've already changed everything to  NotInheritable classes with everything shared. I'll keep this in mind for the future though. Thanks